# How to forcasting in multiple linear regression model?

Tags: statistics

I have a air pollution data with 3 parameters. then how can i predict the upto 2040 in multiple linear regression model in R programming

Answer (score 0):

explanatory_data = data.frame(par1 = data$par1, par2 = data$par2)
predictions = predict.lm(model, explanatory_data)

add more parameters to the dataframe if you require.
This is how predictions can be made for multiple regressions.